# Emacs installation from tar file fails on make [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, make, emacs

I am trying to install Emacs 24.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 by following [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/emacs-24-4-released-install-in-ubuntu-14-04/) guide. I have downloaded Emacs 24.5 package from [FTP](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/) and proceeded with `./configure` which ran ok, but after running `make` getting this error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng16
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [temacs] Error 1
```

Tried the same with Emacs 24.4, and same issue. How to install the missing dependency?

Comment: It seems to build fine on my 14.04.3 system using libpng12 - so I guess what you need to figure out is why `./configure` appears to think you have libpng16 but `make` doesn't find it. Have you manually installed any png libraries?

Comment: @steeldriver nope! my kernel is 3.13.0-74-generic

Comment: What is `apt-cache policy libpng12-dev` and `pkg-config --modversion libpng`?

Comment: @steeldriver http://pastebin.com/jxkqD5Cr

Comment: in that case I'm out of ideas - sorry

Answer (score 2):

You just need to [install `libpng` separately](http://libpng.sourceforge.net/index.html). I had the same exact problem occurring both in 24.4 and 24.5, but after installing it, emacs 24.5 installed normally.

To install, unpack and change directory into `libpng` and :

```
./configure
make check
make install
```